# Make docker running from usb storage

Tags: linux, permissions, external-hard-drive, docker

I try to store my Docker config, images, containers, etc. on a external storage. Following this tutorial
https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-store-docker-images-and-containers-on-an-external-drive/

I have created /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
    "data-root": "/media/user/MYUSB/docker-data"
}
```

But when I plug my usb storage (MYUSB) and start the docker service, this one fail.

```
$ sudo service docker start
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ sudo dockerd --debug
INFO[2023-07-06T12:36:29.650356567+02:00] Starting up                                  
could not create or set daemon root permissions: /media/user/MYUSB/docker-data: chown /media/user/MYUSB/docker-data: operation not permitted
```

And if I restart the computer, the service will create a new clean MYSUB folder instead to store the data, and the system will mount my actual usb storage as MYUSB1 (and not use it to store the docker data).

My system mount my usb key, and the permissions are set to user:user, and not root:root, so maybe it come from here. But I find curious that the docker service (which I guess is run by root) cannot use a user:user storage.

If I try to mount the usb manually with root user. The /media/user/MYUSB folder that I create is set to root:root, until I mount the usb on it: its owner changer to user:user.

I'm a bit disconcerted because it seams that I'm the only one to cross this problem on the internet, even though it doesn't seem to be a unusual config.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. What do you mean by "user mount". Does it have something to do with /media/ instead of /mnt/ ?

Answer (score 1):

From trying some stuff, I deduct that your USB flash drive has FAT32 or another filesystem that does not support POSIX permissions. You cannot use a filesystem like that with Docker. But that’s not all!

Auto-mounted filesystems are not suitable for Docker either, because they are mounted with *nosuid* and *nodev*. A Linux root filesystem (which is what’s commonly inside Docker images) cannot be properly put on it. You can check these using `mount | grep media`. (Auto-mounting typically works using *udisks2* these days.)

First, you should put an appropriate filesystem on your flash drive (like *ext4*).

Then, you must ensure that *udisks2* does not mount the filesystem (with inappropriate options and too late). You can use an *udev* rule to make it ignore the filesystem:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

You’d put this in a file named like `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ignore-my-usb.rules`. You can find the filesystem UUID for your newly created filesystem using `blkid`.

You would then create an appropriate entry in `/etc/fstab` (again using the UUID) to make sure the USB flash drive is mounted early enough. No need to fiddle with any Docker config either, just mount it at `/var/lib/docker`, the default Docker data directory. Something like this:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX  /var/lib/docker  ext4  relatime  0 0
```

To make sure everything works fine just reboot. Docker should start and `mount` should confirm that the flash drive is indeed mounted at `/var/lib/docker`.

Your Docker flash drive is then portable – of sorts. You must not just remove it when the PC is running. Stop Docker first, unmount it and only then remove it. Otherwise you risk filesystem corruption, and Docker would eventually crash of course.

Comment: Thank you. If I followed strictly your instruction, I end up in emergency mode when debian try to boot and that the usb storage is not plugged in. This is because of the fstab instruction, it seems. Alternatively, if I follow your instruction without the fstab instruction and mount manually the usb storage, it works. Is there a way to avoid this error and make it mount at boot ?

Comment: There is no easy solution here. Either you have everything start automatically or you have everything start manually (both Docker and mounting the fs, using the `noauto` option). Maybe look into Podman instead of Docker; it does not use a daemon.